# AngularJS: How can pass a function/filter on ng-click inside a ng-repeat to update the main content

Tags: angularjs

I am pretty new with AngularJS just learning it now. Just a beginner question. I have a bunch of data on a json file. And I need to setup a sidebar with list of person's name that are clickable and once they're clicked the main content w/c is also looped using `ng-repeat` with `limitTo:1` filter need to be update on the right person name data.

Here was my sample code:

**html:**

[image: html code screenshot]

**JS:**

[image: javascript code screenshot]

Hope anyone can help! Any help will deeply appreciated.

Comment: please add your codes as code not as a image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, almost the same scenario covered here: OR see working example here http://jsfiddle.net/pkxPa/91/

```js
function Test($scope) {
    $scope.persons = [{ type: 1, name: 'Caio' }, { type: 2, name: 'Ary' }, { type: 1, name: 'Camila' }, { type: 3, name: 'Daniel' }];
    $scope.myFunction = function (val) {

        return (val.type != 2);
    };
}
```

```html
<div ng-app ng-controller="Test">
    <span ng-click="myFilter = {type: 1}">Type 1</span> |
    <span ng-click="myFilter = {type: 2}">Type 2</span> |
    <span ng-click="myFilter = {type: 3}">Type 3</span> |
    <!-- multiple filter - not working -->
    <span ng-click="myFilter = myFunction">Types 1 & 3</span> |
    <span ng-click="myFilter = null">No filter</span>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="person in persons | filter:myFilter">{{person.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I works when i removed the clickable link on ng-repeat and do it manually just like on the sample above.. but, when doing it dynamically it's like not passing the right value or it just not doing something.